# Issues with displaying data points on every frame of facet_wrap/facet_grid object

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I'm trying to produce a plot with either facet_wrap or facet_grid (no preference at this time), but display a selection of data points on every frame within the facet_wrap/facet_grid object.

I read that you can simply remove the facetting variable from the data set you want included on every plot, but for whatever reason this doesn't seem to be working for me.

This is on Rstudio Version 1.1.453.

I found this code sample:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point(data = transform(mpg, class = NULL), colour = "grey85") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~class)
```

And pretty much copied it for my code below. The above code works fine, but for whatever reason in my implementation it returns an error message. Note I've tried setting both geom features to geom_point also with no luck.

```
ggplot(data = Total, aes(Total$Time, Total$Killing)) + 
  geom_jitter(data = transform(Total, Run = NULL), colour = "grey85") +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~Run)
```

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2700): x, y

This is the error message I've been encountering on attempting to run this code.

Ultimately my goal is to run the below code, but I simplified it a bit for the purposes of the question above.

```
ggplot(data = filter(Total, Cell_Line != "stDev"), aes(x= Time, y=Killing)) + 

  geom_line(data = filter(select(Total, -Run), Cell_Line == "Wild_Type"), aes(x = Time, y = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,3])) +

  geom_errorbar(aes(x = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,2], ymax = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,3] + filter(Total, Cell_Line == "stDev")[,3], ymin = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,3] - filter(Total, Cell_Line == "stDev")[,3])) +

  geom_point() + 

  facet_wrap(~Run)
```

And here's the result of dput(Total) trimmed down to the first 30 rows:

```
structure(list(Cell_Line = structure(c(5L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 14L, 5L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 15L, 14L), .Label = c("17", 
"19", "20", "29", "3", "33", "38", "47", "49", "53", "55", "7", 
"8", "stDev", "Wild_Type"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("00", 
"02", "04", "08", "12", "18", "24", "32", "40", "48", "56", "64", 
"72", "80"), class = "factor"), Killing = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0704388, 0.2881066, -0.0132908, 
0.04700991, 0.03049371, -0.02243472, 0.1513817, 0.129636, 0.09328508, 
0.05876777, 0.1063291, 0.0357473, 0.1974026, 0.07732854, 0.07383331
)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: are you able to share your data with us? You can do this with `dput(Total)` (maybe it's better to shorten the dataframe before)

Comment: Do not use `$` in `aes()`.

Comment: You're right about the $ in the first code sample, it worked once I removed them! I still can't get the longer section of code at the bottom to execute though. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Don't do the filtering inside the `aes` Either do it before or do in in the `data` argument

Comment: Your toy data doesn't have any column named `Run`. How do you pretend to use it as an argument to `transform`?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `transform` has an error: you don't have a column named `Run`.

```
set.seed(1)
Total$Run <- sample(1:100, 30)

# this is your own code:
ggplot(data = Total, aes(Total$Time, Total$Killing)) + 
  geom_jitter(data = transform(Total, Run = NULL), colour = "grey85") +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~Run)
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]